# Cancellation of async Task in ReactiveUI ViewModel (ReactiveObject)

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui, cancellation

I'm currently experimenting with **ReactiveUI** (5.5.1) and I've created a ViewModel (subclass of `ReactiveObject`) which works as an **autocomplete** for a location search (adapted from [mikebluestein/ReactiveUIDemo on github](https://github.com/mikebluestein/ReactiveUIDemo/blob/master/RXUIDemo/SearchResultsViewModel.cs)). Each time the query text changes, a REST service is called which returns matching locations for the submitted query.

**Question:** As you can see in my code below, `DoSearchAsync(string query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` is cancellable, however, I'm not sure as to how (and where in the code) to actually cancel any search - hence using `CancellationToken.None` atm. It might seem as an overkill to cancel requests in this specific use-case, but I wonder how one would *enable* cancellation in this reactiveUI/async-Task scenario anyway.

Code:

```
public class ReactiveLocationSearchViewModel : ReactiveObject {

readonly ReactiveCommand searchCommand = new ReactiveCommand();

public ReactiveCommand SearchCommand { get { return searchCommand; } }

string query;

public string Query
{
    get { return query; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref query, value); }
}

public ReactiveList<Location> ReactiveData { get; protected set; }

public ReactiveLocationSearchViewModel()
{
    ReactiveData = new ReactiveList<Location>();
    var results = searchCommand.RegisterAsyncTask<List<Location>>(async _ => await DoSearchAsync(query, CancellationToken.None));

    this.ObservableForProperty<ReactiveLocationSearchViewModel, string>("Query")
        .Throttle(new TimeSpan(700))
        .Select(x => x.Value).DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Subscribe(searchCommand.Execute);

    results.Subscribe(list =>
    {
        ReactiveData.Clear();
        ReactiveData.AddRange(list);
    });
}

private async Task<List<Location>> DoSearchAsync(string query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // create default empty list
    var locations = new List<Location>();

    // only search if query is not empty
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        ILocationService service = ServiceContainer.Resolve<ILocationService>();
        locations = await service.GetLocationsAsync(query, cancellationToken);
    }

    return locations;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxUI 5.x doesn't have this built-in, but it's easy to fake:

```
var results = searchCommand.RegisterAsync<List<Location>>(
    _ => Observable.StartAsync(ct => DoSearchAsync(query, ct)));
```

In RxUI v6, this is built in:

```
searchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(
    (_, ct) => DoSearchAsync(query, ct));
```

Comment: Wow, you're really nursing your baby :-)
For the readers: Works perfectly after changing searchCommand from type ReactiveCommand to a ReactiveUI.Legacy.ReactiveAsyncCommand.

Looks like this will change in v6 though (legacy...)

Anyway, thanks Paul!

Comment: It should work with the v5 command too, I just had the wrong name

Comment: @paul-betts In your example above, where does the cancellation token come from, i.e. where is its `CancellationTokenSource`? How does one cancel it manually via its token source's `Cancel()` when, say, a button is pressed?

Comment: The cancellation token comes from either unsubscribing from the ExecuteAsync observable, or via explicitly passing a token into ExecuteAsyncTask

Comment: @PaulBetts How exactly does that work? Unsubscribing permanently disconnects the subscribed method, requiring you to resubscribe after every cancellation, and Cancellation token source is a one-use object, so you'd have to reconstruct the entire command after every cancellation. I'm really not understanding how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Nope, the cancellation token is created for you by ReactiveCommand. When I say "Unsubscribe from ExecuteAsync" I mean, unsubscribe from the value returned from ExecuteAsync, not unsubscribe from the Command itself

Comment: Please, give a sample of cancellation using ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask. I still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Update for ReactiveUI 9.x:

#### Define Properties

```cs
// using ReactiveUI.Fody
[Reactive]
public ReactiveCommand<TQuery, IEnumerable<TResult> SearchCommand { get; set; }

private CompositeDisposable Disposables { get; } = new CompositeDisposable();
```

#### In the Constructor

```
// hook up the command
var searchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<TQuery, IEnumerable<TResult>>((query, ct) => DoSearchAsync(query, ct)));
SearchCommand = searchCommand;

// don't forget to subscribe and dispose
searchCommand
    .Subscribe(result => Result = result)
    .DisposeWith(Disposables);
```